# On SQL2012 Enterprise Manager How to change color scheme of 2012 editor to be like 2008 editor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, editor

We recently update our SQL server to 2012. I've been using the SQL 2008 version of SQL editor. I like the color scheme of the 2008 and would like to change the SQL 2012 version to match the same color scheme or close. Also I noted that Visual Studio 2017 opens a SQL file with the proper color scheme.

I've looked through the 
Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors 
Options>Text Editor>
There seems to be no way to change the scheme.

When I open a query with Visual Studio 2017 the color scheme is what I would expect from Enterprise Manager for SQL 2012

Current View:

[image]

This is the formatting scheme I'd like:

[image]

Comment: Could you upload some screen captures?